# PHP - Certain array indexes not accepting variables

Tags: php, arrays, loops, for-loop

I have a bizarre issue that I cannot for the life of me seem to resolve.

I am generating an array ($tags) from a mysql query, it looks something like this:

```
Array(
    [1] => Safety Toe
    [2] => Waterproof
)
```

Then I have another array ($link) I generate in a loop:

```
Array(
    [1] => Array(
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 2
    )
    [2] => Array(
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 2
    )
)
```

Also, I have 2 predefined variables that in this case are as follows:

```
$max == 2;
$title_count == 3;
```

Later on I have 2 for loops, 1 is nested:

```
for($y=0;$y<$max;$y++){
    for($x=1;$x<=$title_count;$x++){
        if($x==1){
            echo "<tr><td>".$tags[$link[$x][$y]]."</td>";
        }elseif($x<$title_count){
            echo "<td>".$tags[$link[$x][$y]]."</td>";
        }else{
            echo "<td>".$tags[$link[$x][$y]]."</td></tr>";
        }
    }
}
```

This should produce something along the lines of:

```
Safety Toe Safety Toe Safety Toe
Waterproof Waterproof Waterproof
```

The problem is this is what I get:

```
Safety Toe Safety Toe Safety Toe
```

This made me curious, so I tried manually inputting $tags[2]. That worked and produced:

```
Waterproof Waterproof Waterproof
Waterproof Waterproof Waterproof
```

However, if I manually set them all to $tags[$link[1][1]] ($link[1][1] == 2) I get an empty result. If I set a variable, such as $test = $link[1][1]; (which echoes as 2), and then try $tags[$test], I get nothing. However if I set $test = 2; and do $tags[$test] I get Waterproof.

I am beyond bewildered here, if there is anything I'm missing, or any ideas as to why this would be the way it is, please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: `$test=$links[1][0]` should be `$test=$link[1][0]`, but I guess that will not solve your problem..

Comment: Why doesn't your code make sense? You have $link[][], which is multi-dimensional, and you are only showing one dimension in your description.

Comment: what is the value of $max?

Comment: @Pieter, That was a left over test function I forgot to remove. I have updated my question.

Comment: @PédeLeão, You are correct, it doesn't because I labeled the arrays wrong in my question, I have fixed it.

Comment: whats the value of $max and $title_count??

Comment: @Suyesh, steven: $max and $title_count are predefined by other variables (and echo the proper amounts) in this case, $max == 2; and $title_count == 3;

I updated my question with those fixed.

Comment: Your `else` statement should only be `echo "</tr>";`. `$x` can become 3 and there is no third element in that array.

Comment: @PédeLeão It does open with <tr> check the first if($x==1). Also, it should echo safety toe 3x then waterpoof 3x on the next line. I only get safety toe 3x. Also, if force the first line to be $tags[$link[1][1]] it echoes nothing on the first line. If I echo $tags[$link[1][1]] anywhere in my code, it produces nothing.

Comment: Is your array like this:
`$link= Array(Array(1,2),Array(1,2));
$tags = Array('Safety Toe', 'Waterproof');`
If yes then when I print it, like below:
`echo '<pre>';
print_r($tags);
print_r($link);`
`Array
(
    [0] => Safety Toe
    [1] => Waterproof
)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )

)`
The index should start from 0. Why it is starting from 1 in your case?

Comment: @RST That is not correct. Check the for loop, it runs if $x<=$max. The elseif is if $x<$max, therefore the last "else" runs when $x==$max, and therefore needs the entire <td></td></tr>.

Comment: @Suyesh If you look at the declaration in my question, I start it at 1. That is because $tags is generated from a mysql table, and the id of the tags table starts at 1. That is why $links[1][0] is 1 and $links[1][1] is 2.

Comment: @sharf my problem is, why would you add an empty `td`? When $x=3 then in the 'else' statement it will try to read `$link[3][0]` and so on which don't exist.

Comment: @RST I don't understand what you are getting at. Are you asking why would I put a blank td if so $link[1][0] and $link [3][0] had values, but $link[2][0] had no value? The answer to that is because IF there is an empty link, I want it to fill with a blank td to keep the spacing properly.

Comment: Provided that you have the third element in the array $link, only then your code will work. So the $link array should be:
`Array(
    [1] => Array(
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 2
    ),
    [2] => Array(
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 2
    ),
    [3] => Array(
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 2
    )

)`
In that case you'll get the following executions:
`echo "<tr><td>"."Safety Toe"."</td>";
echo "<td>"."Safety Toe"."</td>";
echo "<td>"."Safety Toe"."</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>"."Water Proof"."</td>";
echo "<td>"."Water Proof"."</td>";
echo "<td>"."Water Proof"."</td></tr>";`
should work.

Comment: Guess that is what I have been trying to say :(

Comment: @Suyesh I'm sorry I do not understand what you're trying for.

Thanks everyone, I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem, and it would not have been determinable from what I posted.

I tested

```
$tags[intval($links[1][1])]
```

and it worked.The $links array is being generated by exploding a string (1, 2). I was axploding on "," not ", " so the value of the second entry was " 2" instead of "2", hence the intval.

The string needs to be adjusted to "1,2" or the explode needs to be adjusted to ", ". Either way fixes the problem.

Comment: How were we supposed to know that you were `exploding a string (1, 2)` ? -1 for not posting a complete scenario.

Comment: I did not think it was relevant at the time. As I said the array was being generated by a function.